# Rounded Corner using DD_roundies problem IE6+

Tags: jquery, plugins, rounded-corners

I rounded Corner Any div with DD_roundies jquery plugin.

[Website plugin](http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_roundies/)

this plugin worked perfectly. but my div have a any background image ( CSS ) now in FF, Chrome and IE6 worked and show div corner with background but in IE7, IE8 , IE9 Not Show div background and only rounded corner my div.

How To Fix This.
Thanks

Comment: **END OF LIFE STATEMENT** notice how the plugin is dead. Find a different one.

Answer (score 2):

I'd have a look at using an alternative solution that is far more robust called css3pie which you can find [here](http://css3pie.com/).

The instructions are pretty simple and it will allow you to apply rounded corners to elements which then respond to resize events.

As with all polyfills though use it sparingly.

Comment: Once it's compressed and g-zipped it's not that bad. It's light years ahead of any other solution around now too.